# Rails metal http basic auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, basic-authentication

I am trying to use HTTP basic authentication when a remote service hits one of my Rails metal endpoints.

I am wondering how to get access to the username and password of the request. So far, I have printed out the entire env object and can't find the username or password anywhere in that object.

Instead, I see
"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Basic YW5yZ3JpZDpzYWZlbWFpbA==", "PASSENGER_CONNECT_PASSWORD"=>"U4vAn6lVAOe2C8nIQSWT93j3SFJkA5VxOicSeDspF9a"

But I am not sure what to do with this.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
class MyHook
  def self.call(env)
    user = env[...]
    pass = env[...]
    if (user == "foo" && pass == "pass")
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'base64'
# Decode the colon-separated, base64-encoded user and password after "Basic "
user, pass = Base64.decode64(env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split[1]).split ':', 2
```

I would definitely retire the password you posted encoded with your question. :-)